# ArrayFire CPU, will it run out of memory due to late GC?

Tags: out-of-memory, arrayfire

I am not entirely sure how ArrayFire manages memory on the RAM when using CPU mode. Based on task manager observation, it appears the device memory on RAM is not released right away, it looks like there is a GC stage.

Is this true?

What happen if I wanted to allocate a lot of RAM when GC hasn't release the device memory (RAM)? Will I run out of RAM? Or will that triggers GC somehow?

I am running into memory issues when allocating host memory (not device memory) and I still trying to figure out what's wrong. In the meantime, does GC really exists on CPU mode and will it cause out of memory if GC is triggered too late? And how should I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArrayFire will cache allocations and reuse them for later operations. Based on some heuristics or if an allocation fail, ArrayFire will call the garbage collector. You can manually run garbage collector by calling [deviceGC](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__device__func__mem.htm#ga2fa2d8f09a01b92e840c8149630246d6) which will release unlocked(unused) memory.

Comment: Great, thanks. I will do deviceGC just to be sure I get the memory I need.